# Passing a value to javascript code using jsp tag

Tags: jsp

I am writing jsp code and I have a problem passing a constant's value to javascript. Here is my jsp code:

```html
<html:hidden name="myForm" property="<%=MyForm.USERNAME%>"/>
<!-- some HTML code -->
<html:link href="#" styleClass="frameaction" onclick="javascript:verifyUsername(\'<%=MyForm.USERNAME%>\'); return false;">
                    <html:img src="<%=verifyButton%>"/>
</html:link>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```html
function verifyUsername(username) {
  // some calculation to verify username
}
```

I have an error while executing the code above. Instead of passing the value of "MyForm.USERNAME", I receive the string "'<%=MyForm.USERNAME%>'" in "verifyUsername". My jsp code is definitely not right. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Maybe try removing the backslashes that are escaping the quotes.

Comment: Use Expression Language https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html to pass the value to the tag attribute, not the scriptlet. Something like `${MyForm.USERNAME}`.